# Is there any way to stop characters from changing clothes after switching characters?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

*I'm talking about Single Player mode.*

In the Epsilon Program mission, Michael has to wear the stupid uniform for 10 consecutive days. But when i switch to Trevor / Michael, he changes to other clothes.

How can I stop him from changing clothes?

*(well, i think it's a weird question)*

Comment: This doesnt have much to do with it but I hate seeing everyone who talks about this mission use the word, "consecutive". The game clearly says cumulative meaning ten days im general. That's it. It doesn't have to be ten days in a row it's cumulative, not consecutive. Use a dictionary and go to the 'Help' section in the 'Brief' menu if you do not believe me.

Comment: why "hate"? any reference of cumulative instead of consecutive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't stop anyone from changing clothes.

If you want to finish this mission earlier, you can just go to sleep; every time you go to bed (saving not required) time advances by 6 hours. The next mission will be much worse, so you'll need all the rest you can get.

Comment: LOL. Michael needs a lot of sleeps. 10 days / 6 hours per sleep = 40 sleeps !!!

Comment: As Nolonar said, wait till you have to do the next mission.  It makes saving the game 40 times seem like fun!  Kifflom.